# What is the standard practice to bring back valuable information from the chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

I just had a [discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6385/discussion-between-frenchkheldar-and-mythealias?highlights=false) on the chat as one user mythealias helped figure out some of my issues related with my question. I feel like there are some valuable information from our back and forth. Should it be brought back to the question? Is the link to the chat in the comments sufficient? Should we just star the good bits? Part of my desire to bring things back is to either upvote or reward some of the material. But obviously, if I do it, I cannot upvote my summary, that would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 8):

If the discussion in the chat room gives you ideas as to how to clarify your question, then do so by editing the question, and you can incorporate the content of the discussion that way.

If the discussion in the chat room constitutes an answer to the question, or leads you to figure out an answer, then turn it into an answer and post it. Or you could ask that one of the other participants in the discussion post the answer.

If the discussion helps clarify an existing answer, then you could leave a comment pointing the author of that answer to the chat transcript, so they can incorporate the material if they want. Or you could post a separate answer with the clarified version.

P.S. When I say "turn it into an answer" I don't mean that you should copy and paste the chat transcript into an answer. That'd be inappropriate. I mean that you should write an answer motivated by the things that were discussed in chat.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a summary of the good stuff can be put into a new answer to the question. I think a user can give more than one answer to a question. With this the good stuff would be better visible to everybody than in a poorly titled chatroom and it would be upvotable.